# Alternative compound key ranges in CouchDB

Tags: nosql, mapreduce, couchdb

Assuming a mapreduce function representing object relationships like:

```
function (doc) {
    emit([doc.source, doc.target, doc.name], null);
}
```

The normal example of filtering a compound key is something like:

```
startKey = [ a_source ]
endKey   = [ a_source, {} ]
```

That should provide a list of all objects referenced from **a_source**

Now I want the oposite and I am not sure if that is possible. I have not been able to find an example where the *variant* part comes first, like:

```
startKey = [ *simbol_first_match* , a_destination ]
endKey   = [ {} , a_destination ]
```

Is that posible? Are compound keys (1) filter and (2) sort operations within a query limited to the order of the elements appear in the key?

I know I could define another view/mapreduce, but I would like to avoid the extra disk space cost if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148442/how-exactly-is-startkey-and-endkey-working-in-couchdb/17150153#17150153) where I explained how keys work in view requests with CouchDB.

Compound keys are nothing special, no filtering or anything. Internally you have to imagine that there *is* no array anymore. It's just syntactic sugar for us developers. So `[a,b] - [a,c]` is treated just like `'a_b' - 'a_c'` (with `_` being a special delimiter).